# get items from a list and it's inner list into one list?

Tags: c#, linq, list

i have a list

```
public class Org
{
  public string Name;
  public List<OrgPost> OrgPostCollection= new List<OrgPost>();
}

public class OrgPost
{
  public string OrgPostTitle;
}
```

and have:

```
List<Org> OrgCollection=//GetAll(Org);
```

and now i have a list of org like this

```
   [Name,OrgPostCollection]
   [Name2,OrgPostCollection2]
   ...
```

but i need something like this:

```
   [Name1,OrgPostCollection[0]]
   [Name1,OrgPostCollection[1]
   [Name2,OrgPostCollection[0]]
   [Name2,OrgPostCollection[1]]
   ...
```

Comment: Not a complete answer, but do you know [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a nested select:

```
   var flatEnumerable = from o in OrgCollection
                        from p in o.OrgPostCollection
                        select new Tuple<Org, OrgPost>(o, p);
```

You can then project whatever you want in the `select`, I project a `Tuple<Org, OrgPost>`.

The result `flatEnumerable` is `IEnumerable<Tuple<Org, OrgPost>>`, you can then call `ToList` or `ToArray` to resolve the enumerable into a list or array:

```
List<Tuple<Org, OrgPost>> flatList = flatEnumerable.ToList();
Tuple<Org, OrgPost>[] flatArray = flatEnumerable.ToArray();
```